# SQL Sum rows in column based on active date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Column value "DateThru" that has a date value that changes depending on the database update day. I have a few tables inner join'd and i'm trying to get a sum of a column (Alloc) up to the "DateThru" date.  I tried limiting the table using

```
  where ActivityDate <='DateThru'
```

But i'm getting server errors any time i try in where clause.

The table I am pulling from looks like this

```
    Month  ActivityDate  Alloc
    ---------------------------
     x     2017-10-01    .0238
     x     2017-10-02    .0302
     x     2017-10-03    .0156
     x     2017-10-04    .0200
     x     2017-10-05    .0321
     x     2017-10-06    .0123
     x     2017-10-07    .0248
```

Say "DateThru" is 2017-10-05.
I want to sum Alloc  from 10-1 to 10-5 giving result of ".122" As MTDAlloc.

Can this be done as a "windows function" or in where clause?
Thanks!

I used sum over partition to get the total

I have The total working and organized correctly.  My issue is now i have duplicate entries for each "r".   so when I change the ActiveDate <= DateThru to just "=" it fixes my duplicate issue but does not total the MTDAlloc. I do use a "sum column" to create another so i cant use rownumber() rank to remove duplicates.

```
    Month  rep  goal  MTDAlloc
    ----------------------
    x    r1    20    .122          
    x    r1    20    .122  
    x    r1    20    .122          
    x    r2    20    .122
    x    r2    20    .122        
    x    r2    20    .122
```

The end result will have each unique "r" on one row.

```
    Month  rep  goal  Alloc
    ----------------------
    x    r1    20    .122         
    x    r2    20    .122
```

Really Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Can you show the expected outcome of your MTDAlloc column?

Comment: if all you want is a sum of Alloc.. then should it be something like 

Select Month, rep,goal, sum(Alloc) from your table group by month, rep, goal

or am i missing something else?

Comment: I got it using the sum over partition! just having a duplicate issue doe to the <= where clause now.

Comment: Can you show your query please?

Comment: Post Edited with Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may merely be single quotes.  From what you describe, this should work:

```
where ActivityDate <= DateThru
```

The single quotes make the value a string.  The comparison to a date makes SQL Server want to convert it to a date.  And `'DateThru'` is not recognized as a valid date.

EDIT:

My guess is that despite its name, `DateThru` is really a string.  You can find the offending values by using:

```
select DateThru
from . . .
where try_convert(datetime, DateThru) is null;
```

Comment: I have tried and i continue to get externaldata_1 errors.  If i set ActivityDate ='2017-10-05' it works though just for that date.

Comment: @MattMcDermott . . . That suggests that `DateThru` is a string representation -- and that not all values are valid dates.